# How to use Visual studio code with Qt/Qmake? (macOS)

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code, qmake

How to use Qt with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? I have Qt 5.15.1 installed which builds my code for macOS, Android and iOS.

Is it possible to have Visual Studio Code build my Qt application for macOS, Android and iOS like QtCreator does?

**Environment:**
My developer environment is macOS Catalina.

Comment: My recommendation is that you use qmake but CMake : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: If switching to cmake requires me to change the `.pro` files in my project, then that would be a path of high resistance for me. I was looking for an easy "configure once with qmake" and use it like QtCreator if that was possible at all

Comment: If you want to keep using qmake then you must use QtCreator. If you want to use other IDE then it is advisable to use cmake, besides, currently Qt advises that you should prefer cmake over qmake

Comment: Aha, then it looks like I should try the cmake route. Thanks for sharing the info that Qt officially recommends and supports cmake. I am hoping Qt has made it easy to use cmake when building for Android and iOS as well

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cmake, which you should, then all you need to do is configure your cmake project to point to your Qt folder, which basically means setting the project's `Qt5_dir` env variable to point to your Qt installation.

Here's what you need to do to get Visual Studio Code to work with Qt using Microsoft's [CMake Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools):

- Verify that you really have Qt installed,
- Install Microsoft's [CMake Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools),
- Open CMake Tools extension's "Edit CMake Cache (UI)"

  - click on "CMake extension" on vscode's [activity bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) to open "CMake: project outline",
  - click on the "View and more actions" button (i.e., elipsis on upper right corner of the project outline.
- Edit CMake's cache to point `Qt5_dir` to `${QTINSTALLDIR}/5.15.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5`
- Rebuild project.

You can achieve the same goal by using cmake-gui to configure your cmake project.

If instead you really want to stick with qmake then it's enough to setup a [build task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) that runs qmake.